# Scroll is not changing with overflow-y scroll and border radius

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In my page, I have a div that will hold a large quantity of text. I would like to use the scroll value for overflow-y property. However, as I would like to style it, the scroll bar does not transform with the radius. Here is the jsfiddle to go along with it:

https://jsfiddle.net/cjbruin/kkve1bas/

and the code:

HTML

```
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse eget
        turpis nisi. Sed pellentesque urna a fringilla feugiat. Vivamus consequat
        vitae risus nec congue. Nulla faucibus hendrerit velit vitae euismod.
        Pellentesque efficitur efficitur aliquet. Vivamus ut nunc mi. Fusce 
        aliquam quam sit amet malesuada lacinia.

        Aenean vulputate sagittis porta. Nullam vehicula tellus a erat malesuada gravida.
        Vestibulum vulputate eros consectetur ipsum luctus fermentum. Cras consequat
        sollicitudin elit, sed tempor nulla gravida ac. Donec in porttitor ipsum. Sed
        a nisi nec massa euismod tincidunt sed vitae justo. Phasellus a nunc commodo,
        imperdiet nulla vitae, sollicitudin mi. Pellentesque aliquet faucibus sapien et
        congue. In vel diam vitae orci interdum sollicitudin. In a tristique libero,
        vitae finibus metus. Aliquam porttitor justo sed iaculis cursus.

        Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere
        cubilia Curae; Mauris massa arcu, pellentesque eu libero vitae, volutpat
        eleifend eros. Quisque ut ultrices dui. Mauris quis
    </div>
```

CSS

```
div {
        height: 300px;
        width: 400px;
        border: 2px solid black;
        overflow-y: scroll;
        border-radius: 7%;
    }
```

Is there anyway to fix this using CSS3? Or will I have to use JS/jQuery to fix it?

Comment: Your statement is misleading " the scroll bar does not transform with the radius". Anyway good catch @Sonny

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```css
.wrapper {
  padding: 15px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  height: 300px;
 width: 400px;
  border-radius: 7%;
}
.wrapper div {
  height: 300px;
  width: 400px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    padding-right: 10px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper"><div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse eget
  turpis nisi. Sed pellentesque urna a fringilla feugiat. Vivamus consequat
  vitae risus nec congue. Nulla faucibus hendrerit velit vitae euismod.
  Pellentesque efficitur efficitur aliquet. Vivamus ut nunc mi. Fusce 
  aliquam quam sit amet malesuada lacinia.

  Aenean vulputate sagittis porta. Nullam vehicula tellus a erat malesuada gravida.
  Vestibulum vulputate eros consectetur ipsum luctus fermentum. Cras consequat
  sollicitudin elit, sed tempor nulla gravida ac. Donec in porttitor ipsum. Sed
  a nisi nec massa euismod tincidunt sed vitae justo. Phasellus a nunc commodo,
  imperdiet nulla vitae, sollicitudin mi. Pellentesque aliquet faucibus sapien et
  congue. In vel diam vitae orci interdum sollicitudin. In a tristique libero,
  vitae finibus metus. Aliquam porttitor justo sed iaculis cursus.

  Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere
  cubilia Curae; Mauris massa arcu, pellentesque eu libero vitae, volutpat
  eleifend eros. Quisque ut ultrices dui. Mauris quis
    </div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following CSS (::-webkit-scrollbar-xxx) to style your scroll bar, or apply this "sidebar" class to your div.

```
.sidebar::-webkit-scrollbar{
    width:5px;
    background-color:#303949;
}

.sidebar::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{
    background-color:#cccccc;
}
.sidebar::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover{
    background-color:#cccccc;
}

.sidebar::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:active{
    background-color:#cccccc;
} 

.sidebar::-webkit-scrollbar-track{
    border:1px #303949 solid;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 5px 303949 inset;
}
```

Comment: Is .sidebar a class applied to the <div> in the HTML?

Comment: Yes, mentioned it in my answer above.